# Front-end Node NPM Modules and multiple downloads of same dependency

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, shared

Node/NPM newbie with a front-end dev question. I understand one of the strengths of an NPM-type module is that its dependencies get installed within itself, in node_modules. Modules always have the code that they need, and outside libs don't conflict.

That said, seems like this would result in the client downloading the same lib+ver (say, jquery v.X) multiple times. What's the technique for specifying that a module needs a dependency but that it shouldn't package that code if the dependency is already available on the site/page? Does said technique involve parent modules that make the shared lib+ver available?

Or, should various front-end modules just re-download the same lib+ver that other modules on the page might have already downloaded?

Comment: I suppose that when I script a build, I don't concat shared libs and I specify that html script tags be generated to download the shared library if req'd by the module. Also better for browser caching. Or, other way? Should I just concat all libraries needed for a specific module and not worry about the extra weight?

Answer (score 0):

The client will only grab files from that folder that are needed, so if it's linked in HTML once the client will only grab it once. NPM handles dependency duplicates automatically.

Having said that, normally you will want to only serve a static folder to the client without revealing your entire server structure. This can be achieved using:

`app.use(express.static('server/public')`

where 'server/public' is the directory relative to the server.js file that you want to serve. In this case, 'public' contains all my linked view files, stylesheets, JS files, etc. that are linked from the HTML pages. You don't need to move that module's dependencies there as well.

The downside to this is that you'd have to manually move dependencies into the public folder (I make a 'vendor' directory usually) and link from there. It's more work but it's much more efficient and safer in the long run.

NOTE: when using a static folder to serve files, your HTML links will be served from a relative path to that folder.

Comment: Thanks, joh ... that middleware looks like a nice option for security. For now, I'm coming from old-school manual css and js linking and trying to get my head around managing all that via node. Actually I'm seeing that "webpack" allows for "code splitting" to sharedLibs vs page-specific js files ... I'm grokking that more easily at this point :-)